# Expected value of the product of functions of two dependent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

We have two independent normally distributed random variables $X$ and $Y$.

$X\sim N(0,1)$, but somehow $Y\sim N(X,2|X|)$, that is, the mean and variance of $Y$ depend on $X$. (or more generally, they can be functions of $X$)

We have $E(XY)=E({X})E({Y})$, becasue $Cov(X,Y)=E(XY)-E({X})E({Y})=0$

Can we still split up the following expression like this? (or any nonlinear transformations)

$E(e^{X}e^{Y})=E(e^{X})E(e^{Y})$

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say "somehow" but in fact what you're saying is perfectly fine. What you've saying is that $Y$'s distribution *conditional on $X$* is normal with parameters depending on $X.$ Models of this type are common, for instance mixture models.

As for your question, in order to have $E(e^Xe^Y) = E(e^X)E(e^Y)$ you'd need independence (or some reason to expect that particular factorization would hold in the absence of independence, which is possible but unusual.) But here $X$ and $Y$ are not independent (knowing $X$ tells you a lot of probabilistic information about $Y$) so I see no reason why it would hold.

Comment: Thanks! What I was thinking was $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$, because the covariance between $X$ and $Y$ are zero. Just wondering what would happen if impose a nonlinear transformation.

Comment: @J.Wu Independence is pretty much equivalent to $E(f(X)g(Y))=E(f(X))E(g(Y))$ for any functions $f$ and $g.$ Uncorrelated is only special case where $f(x) = g(x) = x$ and in general won't imply it for other functions. However, I'm not sure you're right about $X$ and $Y$ being uncorrelated here. Since $X$ is the conditional mean of $Y$ aren't $X$ and $Y$ positively correlated?

Answer (score 0):

In the particular case you are presenting maybe resorting to the lognormal distribution may help.

If $Z\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then the variable $e^Z$ follows a lognormal distribution whose expectation is $e^{\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}}$. So, in your case:
$$E(e^X)=e^{0+\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$E(e^X e^Y)=E(E(e^X e^Y|X))=E(e^Xe^{X+|X|})=E(e^{2X+|X|})$$
$$E(e^X)E(e^Y)=e^{\frac{1}{2}}E(E(e^Y|X))=e^{\frac{1}{2}}E(e^{X+|X|})$$

Now we have to check if the two last expectations are equal.